# Removing an SVN location from Eclipse using Subclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have added locations into Eclipse so I can, say, create projects from SVN locations.

I am no longer using one of the SVN locations, but it still comes up in the list that appears when I go to **Team > Create project from SVN location**.

How can I remove this SVN location from the list, using Subclipse?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> Window -> show view -> Other... -> SVN repositories

lists the available repositories and lets you delete the one you don't want any more.

Answer (score 11):

Follow these steps:

- Goto "SVN Repositories Exploring"
  perspective.
- You will get "SVN repositories" view.
- "SVN repositories" view shows list of
  locations.
- You can right click on location and
  select "Discard Location" menu.

Hope this helps.

Comment: **Note for the reader:** A location can't be discarded if it is connected to a project.

Answer (score 2):

I had to disconnect the local project first, before I was able to discard the svn location using Spring Tool Suite 2.9.2.

1. So I closed out the project,
2. went to the svn repository perspective,
3. discarded the location,
4. then I reopened the project.

Answer (score 2):

Open your ***SVN repository exploring***, then right click on the location that you want to remove and click ***Discard Location***

**NB.** before doing that, disconnect all projects that are connected to this repository location.
To disconnect a project from SVN repository follow this: 
Right click on the connected project -> **Team** -> **Disconnect...**

Answer (score 0):

If are you looking for how to remove/clear the unused Urls from the "Add SVN Repository" dialog, the way "under the hood" is to edit/delete the file located under `<Eclipse Workspace Location>\.metadata\.plugins\org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui\dialog_settings.xml`

Comment: well it's good to know that config is there, the problem to remove svn repositories isn't solved with this answer. You just cannot delete repositories there

Answer (score 0):

Be careful not to deleting the project when removing a repository location, the plugin developers where not smart enough to advidce clearly that the project is delected